# Entity Framework : Access child entities by navigations property name's string

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 6 (Database First ).

When i have an object i can access its Childs like this :

```
For each chld in Myobject.Child1
..... do something with chld.....
Next.
```

But let's suppose that i have an object as a variable (Varobj1) , and in a list ( Navig_list) , i have the names of some of its navigations properties :

```
{"Child1","Child2"}
```

How can i do the same thing as above so :

```
For each str in Navig_list
   For each chld in ?????? ( Varobj1.????? )
   ..... do something with chld.....
   Next
Next
```

So how can i access the child collection in this case ?
Thank you !

Comment: This does not make any sense. Can you explain what your doing and what your expectations are. You can't access Navigation properties by a string.

Comment: So the navigation list contains strings that are supposed to be the names of the navigation properties of `Varobj1`,  and you want to access childs of those properties?

Comment: @ lourayad  Yes , and i want to access like i have explained.

Comment: @OnefineDay Why don't make sense. Let' suppose that i want to have a general function that take an object as argument , and a list with some of its navigation property's names and return a list of all these childs. But i want a general function that takes the object as variable and navigation properties as a list of strings.

Comment: @OnefineDay  you think that doesn't exist any possibility for example using reflection  ?

Comment: @alex I've used `CallByName` to perform this type of dynamic operation. Check out the documentation on it.

Comment: @craig Where can I read more for this CallByName ?

Comment: You can read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Craig I try to translate this expression : MyObject.MyChild.ElementAt(1) , using the CallbyName like this : CallByName(MyObject,"MyChild",CallType.Get).ElementAt(1) , but I get an error : Public member 'ElementAt' on type 'HashSet(Of MyChild)' not found. What can I do ?

Comment: @alex, check out my additional answer with a code sample using CallByName which hopefully mimics to a degree what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

Here is an example of using CallByName (see my comment in the previous answer). This worked successfully for me.

```
Private Sub TestCallByName()
    Dim r = New Root
    r.Child1.Add(New Grover With {.x = "Cleveland", .y = "Monkey"})

    Dim h = CallByName(r, "Child1", CallType.Get, {})

    Dim enumerator = CType(CallByName(h, "GetEnumerator", CallType.Method, {}), IEnumerator)

    Do
        If Not enumerator.MoveNext Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        Dim element = enumerator.Current

        Dim x = CallByName(element, "x", CallType.Get, {})
        Dim y = CallByName(element, "y", CallType.Get, {})

        Debug.Print(String.Format("{0}:{1}", x, y))
    Loop
End Sub

Private Class Root
    Public Child1 As New HashSet(Of Grover)
End Class

Private Class Grover
    Public x As String
    Public y As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you friend , but this doesn;t help me , because on your expression you have used Ctype to a known type Hashset(Of Grover). But the problem that if you understand I'm trying to find a way to have all these variables. So  varobj1 is variable , the navigation properties name are also unkown at the begin and are strings in a list. so I can't use hashset(of Grover). Please try to understand that I want to create a expression where main object , and child's navigation properties are variables. If I know them I wouldn't;t use callbyname , but just Myobject.child1.Elementat(0).

Comment: See latest edit - you can call CallByName from the first result. All late-bound with no knowledge of the underlying type.

Comment: again I get an error on the line : Dim element = CallByName(h, "ElementAt", CallType.Get, {0})----
Public member 'ElementAt' on type 'HashSet(Of Child1)' not found.

Comment: OK the latest edit should work. The reason the ElementAt was not working is that it is a generic extension method in the Linq.Enumerable namespace. To compensate, I emulated what ElementAt does, which is to traverse the HashSet's enumerator. Note that CallByName is just a convenient shortcut to calling reflection members on the object's type - you can accomplish the same thing by using reflection directly (though I prefer CallByName as it's easy to read).

Comment: I get an error on the line : Dim enumerator = CType(CallByName(h, "GetEnumerator", CallType.Method, {}), IEnumerator).........Error 103 Too few type arguments to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of T)'

Comment: Sorry, I wish I knew what was going on. I did test the above code exactly as specified and it worked. Typically, objects will implement both generic and non-generic enumerators. I do have option strict on and option infer on, so not sure if we're seeing differences there. For whatever reason, the cast in my example to the non-generic IEnumerator was successful, hence, I could mess with it at that point. Hope you find a solution!

Comment: The only difference is that in my case the Child collection is declared like this :------- Public Overridable Property Child1 As ICollection(Of Child1) = New HashSet(Of Child1) .------ ( this is as created by wizard when I have crerated Model.edmx ).

Comment: and sorry but this "IEnumerator" is a type ? ( because is inside of Ctype). But on my application I try to declare a variable : Dim enu as Ienumerator------ and this produce the same error as above.

Comment: It's an interface type, yes.

Comment: Bu then why your code doesn't work on my objects ? I repeat the only difference is that the Child collection is declared like this :------- Public Overridable Property Child1 As ICollection(Of Child1) = New HashSet(Of Child1) .------ ( this is as created by wizard when I have crerated Model.edmx ). But I think this is not related with the Ienumerator error. Is there something that I should include in order that my code to know Ienumerator ?